Raise on-screen keyboard on touchscreen devices after image upload
Right after the image is uploaded to the site, i.e. "Add picture" is clicked, we see the text "enter image description here". That text is selected so the following keyboard input replaces that text ... on regular non-touchscreen devices.
Here's what happening on touchscreen screen device like iPad:



As you can notice, text is selected, but there is no on-screen keyboard. To enable keyboard it's necessary to drop the current selection. This makes the whole process of describing the recently uploaded image harder.
I suppose that selecting text right after the image uploading should raise the on-screen keyboard on touchscreen devices, or at least should allow manual keyboard raising without losing the selection.
Reproduced: iPad Pro 11" iPadOS 17.5.1, Google Chrome 126.0.6478.153
